# neo4j : "Parse Generalized time, invalid format"

Tags: neo4j

neo4j: Database failed to start: DB

I installed Neo4j Destop 1.1.8 in window10 but could not start the database, including I could not access the page. localhost: 7474, browser Notify that this site can not be accessed.

I have installed Zulu and java 8.

Screen says

> Database failed to start: DB [database-*****-****-***-*****-*******] 'v3.4.6' exited with status 'KILLED'. Check the logs

And here are my logs.

```
2018-08-25 08:45:11.051+0000 ERROR Failed to start Neo4j: Starting Neo4j failed: Component 'org.neo4j.server.database.LifecycleManagingDatabase@2f17e30d' was successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see the attached cause exception "Parse Generalized time, invalid format". Starting Neo4j failed: Component 'org.neo4j.server.database.LifecycleManagingDatabase@2f17e30d' was successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see the attached cause exception "Parse Generalized time, invalid format".
org.neo4j.server.ServerStartupException: Starting Neo4j failed: Component 'org.neo4j.server.database.LifecycleManagingDatabase@2f17e30d' was successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see the attached cause exception "Parse Generalized time, invalid format".
    at org.neo4j.server.exception.ServerStartupErrors.translateToServerStartupError(ServerStartupErrors.java:68)
    at org.neo4j.server.AbstractNeoServer.start(AbstractNeoServer.java:220)
    at org.neo4j.server.ServerBootstrapper.start(ServerBootstrapper.java:111)
    at org.neo4j.server.ServerBootstrapper.start(ServerBootstrapper.java:79)
    at com.neo4j.server.enterprise.CommercialEntryPoint.main(CommercialEntryPoint.java:22)
Caused by: org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifecycleException: Component 'org.neo4j.server.database.LifecycleManagingDatabase@2f17e30d' was successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see the attached cause exception "Parse Generalized time, invalid format".
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:466)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.start(LifeSupport.java:107)
    at org.neo4j.server.AbstractNeoServer.start(AbstractNeoServer.java:212)
    ... 3 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error starting org.neo4j.kernel.impl.factory.GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory, C:\Users\Sarandar\.Neo4jDesktop\neo4jDatabases\database-3d6b2a11-4a4c-4be3-9270-cbe4e3e639f0\installation-3.4.6\data\databases\graph.db
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.factory.GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.initFacade(GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.java:212)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.enterprise.EnterpriseGraphDatabase.<init>(EnterpriseGraphDatabase.java:39)
    at org.neo4j.server.enterprise.OpenEnterpriseNeoServer.lambda$static$1(OpenEnterpriseNeoServer.java:78)
    at org.neo4j.server.database.LifecycleManagingDatabase.start(LifecycleManagingDatabase.java:88)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:445)
    ... 5 more
Caused by: org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifecycleException: Component 'org.neo4j.kernel.extension.KernelExtensions@2dd80673' failed to initialize. Please see the attached cause exception "Parse Generalized time, invalid format".
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.init(LifeSupport.java:427)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.init(LifeSupport.java:62)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.start(LifeSupport.java:98)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.factory.GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.initFacade(GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.java:208)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to initialize SSL encryption support, which is required to start this connector. Error was: Failed to load public certificate chain: C:\Users\Sarandar\.Neo4jDesktop\neo4jDatabases\database-3d6b2a11-4a4c-4be3-9270-cbe4e3e639f0\installation-3.4.6\certificates\neo4j.cert
    at org.neo4j.bolt.BoltKernelExtension.createSslContext(BoltKernelExtension.java:243)
    at org.neo4j.bolt.BoltKernelExtension.lambda$createConnectors$0(BoltKernelExtension.java:204)
    at java.util.stream.Collectors.lambda$toMap$58(Collectors.java:1321)
    at java.util.stream.ReduceOps$3ReducingSink.accept(ReduceOps.java:169)
    at java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1374)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:481)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:471)
    at java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:708)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:499)
    at org.neo4j.bolt.BoltKernelExtension.createConnectors(BoltKernelExtension.java:188)
    at org.neo4j.bolt.BoltKernelExtension.newInstance(BoltKernelExtension.java:165)
    at org.neo4j.bolt.BoltKernelExtension.newInstance(BoltKernelExtension.java:84)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.extension.KernelExtensions.newInstance(KernelExtensions.java:78)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.extension.KernelExtensions.init(KernelExtensions.java:61)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.init(LifeSupport.java:406)
    ... 12 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to load public certificate chain: C:\Users\Sarandar\.Neo4jDesktop\neo4jDatabases\database-3d6b2a11-4a4c-4be3-9270-cbe4e3e639f0\installation-3.4.6\certificates\neo4j.cert
    at org.neo4j.kernel.configuration.ssl.SslPolicyLoader.loadCertificateChain(SslPolicyLoader.java:293)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.configuration.ssl.SslPolicyLoader.loadOrCreateLegacyPolicy(SslPolicyLoader.java:161)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.configuration.ssl.SslPolicyLoader.getOrCreateLegacyPolicy(SslPolicyLoader.java:137)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.configuration.ssl.SslPolicyLoader.getPolicy(SslPolicyLoader.java:118)
    at org.neo4j.bolt.BoltKernelExtension.createSslContext(BoltKernelExtension.java:238)
    ... 27 more
Caused by: java.security.cert.CertificateParsingException: java.io.IOException: Parse Generalized time, invalid format
    at sun.security.x509.X509CertInfo.<init>(X509CertInfo.java:169)
    at sun.security.x509.X509CertImpl.parse(X509CertImpl.java:1804)
    at sun.security.x509.X509CertImpl.<init>(X509CertImpl.java:195)
    at sun.security.provider.X509Factory.parseX509orPKCS7Cert(X509Factory.java:471)
    at sun.security.provider.X509Factory.engineGenerateCertificates(X509Factory.java:356)
    at java.security.cert.CertificateFactory.generateCertificates(CertificateFactory.java:462)
    at org.neo4j.ssl.PkiUtils.loadCertificates(PkiUtils.java:161)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.configuration.ssl.SslPolicyLoader.loadCertificateChain(SslPolicyLoader.java:289)
    ... 31 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Parse Generalized time, invalid format
    at sun.security.util.DerInputBuffer.getTime(DerInputBuffer.java:385)
    at sun.security.util.DerInputBuffer.getGeneralizedTime(DerInputBuffer.java:271)
    at sun.security.util.DerInputStream.getGeneralizedTime(DerInputStream.java:541)
    at sun.security.x509.CertificateValidity.construct(CertificateValidity.java:96)
    at sun.security.x509.CertificateValidity.<init>(CertificateValidity.java:128)
    at sun.security.x509.X509CertInfo.parse(X509CertInfo.java:656)
    at sun.security.x509.X509CertInfo.<init>(X509CertInfo.java:167)
    ... 38 more
```

How can I solve this problem? Thanks for the help.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Now I can solve the problem.
Just change my location computer to US